# ILogger in Asp.net Core and Serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have a question,

Is there any concern if I use ILogger in Serilog on behalf of Microsoft logger?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger);
}
```

Then use from ILogger in Serilog namespace.

```
 _logger.Error(exception, "Error", exception.Message, exceptionId);
```

What is your idea?

Comment: `Log.Logger` is already a static singleton, you don't need to register it with DI, just use the static Logger directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft.Extensions.ILogger is an abstraction that decouples your application code (the code that writes log entries) from the underlying logging framework.

Using this abstraction brings the benefit, that you could easily change the Logging Framework underneath (e.g. replace Serilog with NLog) and don't have to update all references in your application code.

Also using Microsoft's abstractions also allows you to configure logging of your application code and logging of Microsoft SDKs you might use at a single place.

The downside of abstractions is that you have to aggree to a common minimum interface provided by all logging frameworks. It's not so easy to use Framework-Specific features this way.

So most of the time i would advise using the abstraction.

If you have very specific features from Serilog you would like to interact with you could think about using ILogger from Serilog directly.
However you can configure serilog in the provider registration as well to a high degree and probably get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

You would configure **Serilog factory interface** to be used instead of built-in **Logger factory** for creating **ILogger**

First in **program.cs**, add the Serilog ILoggerFactory to your IHostBuilder with UserSerilog() method in CreateHostBuilder():

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder => { /* Host configuration */ })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => { /* App configuration */ })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>  { /* Service configuration */})
        .UseSerilog(); // <- Add this line
 }
```

How the library works behind the scenes

On the face of it, completely replacing the default ASP.NET Core logging system to use a different one seems like a big deal. Luckily, thanks to the use of interfaces, loose coupling, and dependency injection, the code is remarkably simple! The whole extension method we used previously is shown below:

```
public static class SerilogHostBuilderExtensions
{
 public static IHostBuilder UseSerilog(this IHostBuilder builder, 
    Serilog.ILogger logger = null, bool dispose = false)
 {
    builder.ConfigureServices((context, collection) =>
        collection.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(services => new 
    SerilogLoggerFactory(logger, dispose)));
    return builder;
  }
}
```

The **UseSerilog()** extension calls the ConfigureServices method on the **IHostBuilder** and adds an instance of the SerilogLoggerFactory as the application's **ILoggerFactory**. Whenever an ILoggerFactory is required by the app (to create an **ILogger**), the **SerilogLoggerFactory** will be used.

for more Information check this [Link](https://andrewlock.net/adding-serilog-to-the-asp-net-core-generic-host/)

Comment: may be not exactly the answer to the question but the answer to my question: How to connect `Serilog` logger to `Microsoft ILogger`.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"The downside of abstractions is that you have to aggree to a common minimum interface provided by all logging frameworks. It's not so easy to use Framework-Specific features this way."

I think we can always create extension methods to overcome this downside.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33486611)